# Can I create a drop down combo box within a list control in wxPython?

Tags: python, list, drop-down-menu, cross-platform, wxpython

I am creating a `wx.ListCtrl` (wxPython 2.8.11.0, Python 2.7) with `style=wx.LC_REPORT|wx.LC_VRULES|wx.LC_SINGLE_SEL` containing a score column (amongst others). Is it possible to make the score for each item (in order of preference):

1. a drop down list of possible scores
2. allow for typing into that column only (I am aware of, though have never used, wx.lib.mixins.listctrl.TextEditMixin)?

EDIT: This needs to be a cross-platform solution.

Answer (score 4):

You can override the OnBeginEdit and check which column has been clicked in using event.m_col and act accordingly (i.e. event.Veto() or not). I don't think you can do a drop down in the cell itself, but you could create a simple dialog that does the same thing when the user clicks on that column. Or you might want to look at the [UltimateListCtrl](http://xoomer.virgilio.it/infinity77/AGW_Docs/ultimatelistctrl_module.html), a pure Python implementation of the ListCtrl that can do just about anything you want.

Comment: Do you mean using `TextEditMixin` for the first part? Also, do you know if `UltimateListCtrl` works cross-platform? The docs only say tested on Windows XP.

Comment: Yeah, I meant with the TextEditMixin. I don't remember the testing status of the UltimateListCtrl. I think it's been used on Linux from what I've seen on the wxPython mailing list. You'll have to ask there to really know.